# Validating JSON query string as query param using Joi

Tags: json, validation, hapi.js, joi

I have a problem of validation JSON that is passed in GET request query param as a serialized string.

What I need to achieve is to parse this serialized string back to JSON and validated it using Joi.

Example: Give is the JSON

```
{
 limit: {size:10, page:0},
 filter: {filter_by: 'foo', filter_val: 'foo', from: '1/1/2016',to: '1/1/2016' }
}
```

And this JSON is converted to query string is:

```
limit%5Bsize%5D=10&limit%5Bpage%5D=0&filter%5Bfilter_by%5D=foo&filter%5Bfilter_val%5D=foo&filter%5Bfrom%5D=1%2F1%2F2016&filter%5Bto%5D=1%2F1%2F2016
```

I need something like this to check:

```
 validate: {
          query: {
            limit: Joi.someMethodToGetJsonFromString.object().keys({
              size: Joi.number(),
              page: Joi.number()
            }
          filter: Joi.someMethodToGetJsonFromString,.object().keys({
              filter_by: Joi.string().valid(['option1', 'option2']),
              filter_val: Joi.string(),
              from: Joi.date(),
              to: Joi.date(),
            }
        }
```

Is there anything in Joi that can help in this scenario, Or I need to write custom validation functions for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to swap out the query string parsing used because hapi doesn't support that format by default. It just uses Node's built in `url` module to parse the URL which doesn't support complex encodings of query strings. You'll need to manually parse it using `qs`, after that you can validate as normal.

### Hapi Version ≥18

You can set your custom parser via [server.options.query.parser](https://hapi.dev/tutorials/routing/?#-query-parameters).

### Hapi Version ≤17

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const Joi = require('joi');
const Url = require('url');
const Qs = require('qs');

const server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 4000 });

const onRequest = function (request, reply) {

    const uri = request.raw.req.url;
    const parsed = Url.parse(uri, false);   // skip the querystring parsing
    parsed.query = Qs.parse(parsed.query);  // parse it ourselves with qs
    request.setUrl(parsed);

    return reply.continue();
};

server.ext('onRequest', onRequest);

server.route({
    config: {
        validate: {
            query: {
                limit: Joi.object().keys({
                    size: Joi.number(),
                    page: Joi.number()
                }),
                filter: Joi.object().keys({
                    filter_by: Joi.string().valid(['option1', 'option2']),
                    filter_val: Joi.string(),
                    from: Joi.date(),
                    to: Joi.date(),
                })
            }
        }
    },
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: function (request, reply) {

        return reply('ok');
    }
});

server.start((err) => {

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log('Started server');
});
```

This is [discussed a little bit in the API docs](http://hapijs.com/api#requestseturlurl-striptrailingslash) under the `request.setUrl()` method.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks,

Comment: I think you could just use Qs against request.query without worrying about the URL - i.e. `Qs.parse(request.query)`